# Pandas drop rows without NAs / keep rows with NAs

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe with missing values in some cells. I want to keep the rows that have nulls in any column. This is the opposite of `pandas.DataFrame.dropna()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [np.nan, 4]})
df

   a    b
0  1  NaN
1  2  4.0
```

desired result:

```
   a    b
1  2  4.0
```

I'd like to do it in the method-chaining style, so something like this would be ideal:

```
df.loc[lambda x: ...]
df.keepna(how='any') # keepna() doesn't exist
```

Comment: Try: `df[df.notnull().all(1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a boolean filter with `df.isnull().any(1)` (if a row has a missing value):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [np.nan, 4]})

df[df.isnull().any(1)]
#   a   b
#0  1 NaN
```

Or the other way: `df[~df.notnull().all(1)]`.

Comment: `df[lambda x: x.isnull().any(1)]` using the chaining style.